# Reading Structs from a spark data frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have read this row from a spark DataFrame:

```
scala> val t = df.take(99)
scala> t(0)(0)
res69: Any = [2,null,WrappedArray([20789823,null,0.0,null,1490788977,1], [50115961,null,0.0,null,1490788977,1], [20787723,null,0.0,null,1490788977,1], [20796254,null,0.0,null,1490788977,1]),null,1488196976]
```

But unfortunately, I do not know how to access the wrapped array within the `Any`.

While I can convert it to String and parse the output string, I am looking for the proper way to access the array.

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/q/33390925/1560062 for `arrays` specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the [`explode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#explode(org.apache.spark.sql.Column)) function? It is somehow similar to a `flatMap` call on collections. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32906613/flattening-rows-in-spark) is an example of using it.

I hope that helps :)