# Spark - scala.MatchError when a List[String] is a field of org.apache.spark.sql.Row?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, collections, apache-spark-sql

I've created a `org.apache.spark.sql.Row` where one of the fields is a `List[String]`. When the Row contained only values like Strings and Booleans it was parsed without any errors. However now when it contains a `List[String]` I'm getting the following error:

```
scala.MatchError: List(, , , , ,) (of class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon)
```

I've made an attempt to convert it to a mutable collection type using `.to[ListBuffer]` but it did not help to solve the problem.

What is the correct way to add `List[String]` as a field to the `org.apache.spark.sql.Row`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access Array column in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33390925/access-array-column-in-spark)

Comment: Can you share your code?